# Refactor string in MySQL field

Tags: mysql, select, sql-update

I searched and couldn´t find something to solve this. I want to update the following table:

```
+--------------------+
| description        |
+--------------------+
| Interna_172_16_1   |
| Interna_172_16_2   |
| Interna_172_16_3   |
| Interna_172_16_4   |
| Interna_172_16_5   |
+--------------------+
```

With the same string, but substracting one from the last number f.e.:

```
+--------------------+
| description        |
+--------------------+
| Interna_172_16_0   |
| Interna_172_16_1   |
| Interna_172_16_2   |
| Interna_172_16_3   |
| Interna_172_16_4   |
+--------------------+
```

How can I accomplish this? sorry for bad english, thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Do this.
The table name has to be adapted

```
UPDATE Table1
SET description = CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`description`, '_', 3)
                   ,'_',SUBSTRING_INDEX(`description`, '_', -1) -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
update yourtable
set description = 
  concat(left(description, length(description)-1), right(description,1)-1)
where right(description,1) regexp '[1-9]+'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a select statement:

```
select concat(
  left(description, length(description) - length(substring_index(description, '_', -1))),
  substring_index(description, '_', -1) - 1
) description                                                         
from tablename
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/r6ic8XsbVT5v56nyFxaNnf/0).
If you want to update the table:

```
update tablename
set description = concat(
  left(description, length(description) - length(substring_index(description, '_', -1))),
  substring_index(description, '_', -1) - 1
);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/r6ic8XsbVT5v56nyFxaNnf/1).
Results:

```
| description      |
| ---------------- |
| Interna_172_16_0 |
| Interna_172_16_1 |
| Interna_172_16_2 |
| Interna_172_16_3 |
| Interna_172_16_4 |
```

This code assumes that all descriptions end with a numeric string.